# Defining positional parameters with apache commons cli

Tags: apache-commons-cli

I would like to define an Apache Commons CLI parser that includes named arguments and positional arguments.

```
program [-a optA] [-b optB] [-f] pos1 pos2
```

How do I validate pos1 and pos2?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One a quick read of the documentation, I was not aware the the CommandLine class would provide access to the remaining positional parameters.

After parsing the Options passed on the command line, the remaining arguments are available in the **CommandLine.getArgs()** method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      DefaultParser clParse = new DefaultParser();
      Options opts = new Options();
      opts.addOption("a", true, "Option A");
      opts.addOption("b", true, "Option B");
      opts.addOption("f", false, "Flag F");

      CommandLine cmdLine = clParse.parse(opts, args); 
      System.out.println(cmdLine.getArgs().length);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This helps me greatly.

Comment: if you do it like this positional arguments are not listen in help.

Comment: In this [Usage Scenarios](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/usage.html) page `getArgs()` isn't mentioned. Though it works and was helpful to me.