# Apache Commons CLI named positional parameters in autoUsage

Tags: apache-commons-cli

It is possible to [retrieve positional parameters in Apache Commons CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35710212/defining-positional-parameters-with-apache-commons-cli).  Is it possible to name them for the usage statement?  To be concrete, [the Apache Commons CLI documentation gives an ls Example](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/usage.html):

```
Usage: ls [OPTION]... [FILE]...
```

How could I use a HelpFormatter to output "[FILE]..." when calling `HelpFormatter.printHelp(..., autoUsage = true)`?  These are the values returned by `CommandLine.getArgs()`.  I know how to name `Option` arguments in a usage message but not how to name such positional arguments.